# How to change the Backup Service user

Tags: backup, service

I am trying to use our BACKUPNAS as the backup storage. We only allow certain users to access the backup folders, and I wonder:

How can I define which domain user will be used for the backup service?

In the backup service settings, I only see : thread and location.

- The farm account will NOT have access to my backup folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 2010 all requirements for a user to be able to perform backups are listed here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748626(v=office.14).aspx

There are different requirements depending on how the backup is performed. For Powershell the user needs to be a member of the local server administration group, and have Full Control on the backup folder for doing a full Farm Backup.

The other scenarios are listed in the link above.

Comment: super - I missed the part that the SQL Server Service also needs access to that folder. (and it uses NETWORK)